# JAX-WS get soap without actually sending to a web-service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

Using JAX-WS and a custom WSDL, is there a way to get the message that would be sent to a web-service without actually making a call to the service? I need to generate a soap message conforming to a WSDL, but that soap message is actually embedded into another message. I was thinking I could create a local web-service that just echos back the message but it seems like there should be a way without doing this or using a handlerchain when it doens't really matter that the message is sent.

Maybe the easiest thing to do is just to generate the soap manually?

Comment: JAX-WS is just an API... which implementation are you using?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?  If so, please share it in answer to your own question.  I'm curious to know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps:

http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-api-for-xml-web-services/writing-a-handler-in-jax-ws.html

You can intercept message before being sent, get the body, get the header, sign it with SAML or whatever you want, and then send it to server.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this example helps (from Understanding Web Services, Part 1: SOAP, IBM Developer Works, page 21):

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();

SOAPPart SOAPPart = message.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope envelope = SOAPPart.getEnvelope();
SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

SOAPElement bodyElement = body.addChildElement(envelope.createName("echo", "req", "http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/MyService/"));

bodyElement.addChildElement("category").addTextNode("classifieds");
message.saveChanges();

SOAPPart SOAPpartbefore = message.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope reqenv = SOAPpartbefore.getEnvelope();

System.out.println(reqenv.toString());
```